# What type is that piece from Kent movieclip?

Tags: identify-this-genre

I am very interested in the video clip released by the Swedish band Kent 4 years ago, introducing their last album and tour.

[Då Som Nu För Alltid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bubOcI11sps)

The whole piece is (or sounds like it is) centered around the drummer girl and its basic rythm (though it changes a little in the meanwhile). Then, more instruments join, and add their own melody, up to the climax, where the music suddenly stops.

This is not a canon (though some canons may sound quite like it), but I am wondering how such a piece would be named. Any idea?

And as bonus question : do you know of similar pieces?
I am quite sure one could find many in classical music, but though I am not totally ignorant about it, I can't remember of such a piece. And I am mainly interested in non-classical musique answers!

Comment: Would *Tubular Bells* or its predecessor [*The Intro and the Outro* - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcrUuCDFLOQ&t=6s) be more recent examples of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descriptively this composition technique is sometimes referred to as "staggered", "layered", or "delayed" entrances. I'm not aware of a general term for music that employs the technique, which cuts across genres.

One genre that uses this layering technique a lot is "epic" music:

- [2-Hours Epic Music | THE POWER OF EPIC MUSIC - Best Of Collection - Vol.5 - 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaXXVzGy7Y8)
- [ZENITH - 2-HOURS | THE POWER OF EPIC MUSIC - Best Of Collection | Vol.6 - 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcNuDPdJbL8)

You can find it frequently in EDM, Movie Trailers, Video game music, and Alan Walker.

Some particularly famous, but very different from each other, classical music examples:

- [Canon in D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvNQLJ1_HQ0) (Pachelbel)
- [Ode to Joy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kcOpyM9cBg) (Beethoven) (and this [flash mob version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbJcQYVtZMo) illustrates it very well!)
- [Bolero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhhkGyJ092E) (Ravel)
- [In C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNi0bukYRnA) (Riley)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as well as your examples. I forgot about Bolero, which is indeed a very good example!!